# Can't install Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, dependencies, 13.10

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 32bit with Gnome 3.8 but am missing the *Ubuntu Software Center*. I tried to install it via terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-center
```

But that tells me that dependencies are not met

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    software-center : Depends: gir1.2-webkit-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
```

`gir1.2-webkit-3.0` depends on `gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0` of version `1.10.2-0ubuntu2`. But that package is only available as version `2.0.4-2~ubuntu13.04`.

I am missing the *Ubuntu Software Center* as well as the *Update Manager* and the packages `update-notifyer` and `ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk`.

How can I install the packages with correct dependencies?

---

#### Edit:

Output of `apt-cache policy gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0`:

```
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0:
  Installed: 2.0.4-2~ubuntu13.04.1
  Candidate: 2.0.4-2~ubuntu13.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.4-2~ubuntu13.04.1 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.10.2-0ubuntu2 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
```

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main

# spotify
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Spotify I added myself.

Comment: You seem to be using outdated packages. You say you are on 13.10, but you _gir..._ version is 2.0.4-2~ubuntu**13.04**, which is not even available on the Gnome 3 PPA. Please post the output of `apt-cache policy gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0` and the relevant lines of your _sources.list_ files.

Comment: I updated my question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `apt-cache policy` is telling you that you are not using the PPA for Gnome 3. I don't know if it's enough to fix your issue, but please try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` and then perform the upgrades.

Comment: It actually did the trick. I added the new repository, removed the version `2.0.4.2` of `gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0` and ran `apt-get install software-center`. Now the dependencies are fine I think. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `apt-get policy` is telling you that `gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0` is locally installed and does not come from a PPA:

```
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0:
...
Version table:
*** 2.0.4-2~ubuntu13.04.1 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This means that your system has no access to the whole set of packages offered by the Gnome 3 PPA. This may cause of many problems, including dependency problems.

Re-add the PPA with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Then update and upgrade your system.

Comment: actually. The dependencies issue was fixed. But unfortunately the software-center keeps crashing. I'll create a new issue for that.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST: run `sudo apt-get update`.
SECOND: the fastest solution is to install `aptitude` with `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and run it: it will find the conflict and propose a solution if you press "!" (watch the red horizontal line in the bottom of the `aptitude` console interface).
Select a solution (any solution which **doesn**'t remove a big number or packets or a kernel should be OK), press G to apply it.
After that exit form aptitude and run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to do a good update and re-check for problems.
Don't remove a kernel or the kernel headers (watch the description of the "linux" packages).
THIRD: After a reboot (superfluous but...) try to install Ubuntu Software Center.
Hope you'll solve. (arrow up if you solve, comment here to ask more questions on the topic)

Comment: why was this voted down? is there anything I should keep in mind that was not mentioned here?

Comment: I tried it, but Synaptic cannot fix my broken dependencies.

Comment: byf-ferdy: Synaptic will not fix your dependencies, `aptitude` (run it from the console) will, because it can offer you multiple choices. Before doing anything run `sudo apt-get update` to update your apt package lists. Please, vote up if this answer is useful.